# Is taking an hour to install typical?

Tags: system-installation

I am having an core 2 dual processor of 2.96Ghz speed and 4GB RAM.
My internet speed is 1Mbps. Still it took more than 1hr to install the ubuntu that too not properly. please help me know, is it common in such a high speed configure desktop for ubuntu to take sooooo long just to install.

Comment: It isn't common, in my experience. Perhaps, in the spirit of questioning you could provide some information on where/when you install slowed down, the sort of configuration you used and ask how this can be improved/prevent; but all in all what you need to do is file a bug report so that someone who can solve this problem finds out about it. :)

Comment: Did you do a net install? 1mb internet is really slow. If you meant 1mB, then the default repo is also really slow. When I do this, I install ubuntu alternative with no packages selected, and then I change the sources.list and then install metapackages myself.

Answer (score 3):

Taking more than ten minutes to install at such a system is not normal - mine is weaker and it installs at around 10 to 15 minutes. Unless , of course, you clicked to update while installing and it is your internet that causes it to be slow.

If you asked for it to update while installing and can't wait because of your internet connection, restart the installation and update after the installation while you use it normally.